# Making a robot autonomous and remotely controlled?

Tags: arduino, webserver, embedded, raspberry-pi, beagleboneblack

I want to design a robot with GPS navigation capable of moving from point A to point B by using GPS coordinates and a compass as a guide. Also I want the robot to be controlled from a website (server) to override the autonomous mode. The robot should provide live camera feed to the server and display the robot location on a map as it is moving to the destination. Here are the components I want to use and what they are used for.

**GPS module:** Provides GPS coordinates to the Robot

**Camera:** Provides live feed to the server

**Wifi module:** Provides internet connection

**Compass:** Provides directions

**Ultrasonic Sensors:** Detects objects and avoid them

I am using [RobotEq motor controller](http://www.roboteq.com/index.php/roboteq-products-and-services/brushed-dc-motor-controllers) to control the motors, however at this point I don't know which motherboard to use.

I am debating between using a Laptop, Beaglebone black, Raspberry PI, Arduino, or a combination of two. Maybe the Arduino can be used for sensors along with a motherboard that has to meet the requirements.

I know JAVA, C/C++, VB.net, and a little of HTML and PHP. Which motherboard should I use? What are the advantages and disadvantages?  I know I might need more components such as USB hub if I was to go with the Beaglebone or less if I was to go with the laptop. But the thing that bothers me the most is how all the things going to be connected together ?

In order for the robot to navigate autonomously, it has to use the GPS, compass, and the sensors data, but at the same time `something` has to control the motor controller. Also I need the GPS coordinates to display the robot on the map, and the camera stream to provide live feed which `something` has to control those as well.

Can I write one software or make an APP that controller all these components and talk to the web server at the same time or how do I go about doing it? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

**Update: As requested by ladislas**

Here is the diagram I came up on how to connect all the components together. I need feedback if this design will work and if it can be improved.

[image]

More details on design.

**Arduino:** It will gather GPS, compass, and all sensors data. It will send it to the laptop through a UART to USB converter.

**Laptop:** It will be responsible for planning the route and controlling the motor controller based on the information coming from the Arduino. It will stream the camera to the webserver and send current GPS of Robot. The laptop will also get the control commands and GPS (Destination) from the website. The program will be written in VB.net.

Comment: The way Stack Overflow works, questions are expected to be about specific technical problems. Questions such as "which programming language is best for this task" are both far too broad and will make answers opinion-based. Also, questions about tool recommendations are off topic for SO.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I am being as specific as I can with the question. I'm just having a hard time figuring out how to connect all the components together and I need clarifications on that mostly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well depending on the side of the robot and on your skills, I would start with the simplest robot as possible.

Starting with a laptop connected via USB to an Arduino can be a good idea: you'll have all the software you need available on your laptop, ease of use and a real interface to see if something's wrong. On the other end, the Arduino will control the motor, the GPS and the sensors. You'll be able to move to a Raspberry Pi if size is an issue.

On the Arduino, you can upload a custom program to interface it with the laptop. It will wait for the laptop instructions before doing anything. On the laptop you can use which ever language you like best as you won't struggle with power or battery, at least in the beginning. On the Arduino you could also use [Firmata](http://www.firmata.org/wiki/Main_Page) but you might need a little more work to get started.

You will also need extra power for the motors and a dedicated shield.

Something is bothering me though: you want live stream and gps localization. I guess you want you robot to move outside. At the same time you want wifi to connect to the server. I might have missed something but if your robot is working outside, you might be far from a wifi hotspot to connect to.

Could you clarify this point?

Hope this will help you get started

Comment: I will be in an area where there will be wifi hotspot while testing the robot, also I can do wifi tethering from my phone. The Arduino is probably not strong enough to control the motors, GPS, compass, and sensors at the same time, right? And I have enough power for the motors. If it is possible to provide any sort of chart or diagram, that would be helpful.

Comment: @Ammar the Arduino can do all sorts of things as long as it is simple. What kind of sensors do you need? If it's just temperature and IMU data, it's quite simple to pull them every now and then. For the GPS it's the same, it should come with an Arduino library for ease of use. If the Uno is too tight, you can go for a Mega2560 which should be more than enough. Controlling motors is also very simple. As for the diagram, I'm not going to do your work ;) Make some and show them to us, we will help you improve the design :)

Comment: I'm only use ultrasonic sensors at this moment. I will work on a diagram and post it here later. Thanks again!

Comment: Please check the diagram.

Comment: @Ammar it's very nice and pretty complete already. :) what kind of motors and motor controler will you use? If it only `pwm`, this can be done with the Arduino. Doing so will only require one interface. It could be much easier.

Comment: I'm using this [motor controller](http://www.roboteq.com/index.php/roboteq-products-and-services/brushed-dc-motor-controllers/xdc2230-detail), I don't really know much about it, but I will stick to the laptop controlling it since it has more processor power. Thanks for checking the design!

Comment: @Ammar oh okay, that's nice! :)